# Memory leakage in python - iterating over pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, memory

I am trying to implement an algorithm to process temporal data.

```
def calculate_frequency(T, Wth):
    k = len(T)
    df = pd.concat(T).sort_values('time')
    frequency = 0
    # some operations commented out that calculate the frequency from T and Wth
    del df
    gc.collect()
    return frequency
```

`T` is a dictionary of time series. A time series is represented as a pandas DataFrame with columns `'alert'` and `'time'`.

I call this function repetitively for different `T`. Surprisingly to me, all the program occupies more and more memory. Any idea how to cope with that?

My attempts so far: deletion of `df` and calling garbage collector.

The manipulations themselves are commented out. They do not impact the memory.

```
import os
import psutil
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import gc
process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
n_data = 10000
n_alert = 40
alert = np.random.randint(0,n_alert,size=n_data).tolist()
time = np.random.rand(n_data).tolist()
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(alert=alert,time=time))
t_all = {}
for a in range(n_alert):
    t_all[a] = df[df['alert']==a]

def calculate_frequency(T):
    df = pd.concat(T).sort_values('time')
    frequency = 0
    # some operations commented out that calculate the frequency from T and Wth
    del df
    gc.collect()
    return frequency

for a in range(n_alert):
    for a2 in range(a):
        T = [t_all[a],t_all[a2]]
        calculate_frequency(T)
        print(process.memory_info().rss)
```

Comment: How are you measuring the memory usage? Show that

Comment: I am just looking into the Task Manager.

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve